# Book recommendation on portfolio theory

Tags: portfolio-optimization, books, soft-question

I am searching for books to self-study on undergraduate level on introduction to portfolio theory that has more math rigor than [Modern Portfolio Theory and Investment Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118469941) and exercise with solutions. [Edward E. Qian, Ronald H. Hua, Eric H. Sorensen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584885580) looks good but it does not provide solutions to the exercises. The book should contain mean-variance analysis, dynamic portfolio allocation, Sharpe ratio, etc.

Comment: From an applied perspective, you can take a look at [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65779/best-books-on-portfolio-construction/65788#65788). Other than that, you can take a look at [Chincarini & Kim (2010), *Quantitative Equity Portfolio Management: An Active Approach to Portfolio Construction and Management*](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000N2HBYI) or [Grinold and Kahn (2020), *Advances in Active Portfolio Management*](https://tinyurl.com/99t79fz8) which is an updated version of their book found [here](https://tinyurl.com/5cyes8wh).

Comment: This book is nice https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Budgeting-Chapman-Financial-Mathematics/dp/148220715X